# Loop through files with specific extension

Tags: matlab, loops, filenames

I need to open many files in a loop, with the same extension.
Example file names are: c1_p1_t_r.mat,c1_p3_t_r.mat,c1_p6_t_r.mat,c1_p7_t_r.mat,c1_p10_t_r.mat,etc.

So basically, the first and last part of the file names are the same, but something in the middle changes.

I tried with:

```
Ext = 'c1_*t_r*.mat';
files = dir(Ext);
```

but it doesn't work. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the file names you shared you should use `c1*t_r.mat` rather than `c1*t_r*.mat`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. It works! But what if for example I have a long extension after 't_' and I don't want to copy the all long file name?

Comment: Check my solution for that.

Comment: @dede I can't really figure out what you need to do. Can you explain it better?

Comment: @alexmogavero, you perfectly answer my question -thanks. I was just wondering if for example I would have had something like: 'c1_sA_t_r_s_u_v_x_z_y_blabla.mat','c1_sB_t_r_s_u_v_x_z_y_blabla.mat','c1_sC_t_r_s_u_v_x_z_y_blabla.mat','c1_sD_t_r_s_u_v_x_z_y_blabla.mat','c1_sE_t_r_s_u_v_x_z_y_blabla.mat', etc.  where after 't_' there is a long extension. In that case,  would     Ext = 'c1_*(asterisk)t_*(asterisk).mat'     have been appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

Use `files = dir('*.Ext');` You need the apostrophes to pass it as a string and the asterisk as the wildcard for file names. I think passing multiple asterisks here is the problem. You might resort to creating the variable name as a full string in case they are as similar though:

```
for ii = 1:NumberOfFiles
    filename = sprintf('c1_p%dt_r.mat',ii);
    %//load file with created name
end
```